# Using Protobuf-Net In Xamarin.iOS without full AOT

Tags: xamarin.ios, protobuf-net

Is there any alternative to achieving serialising and deserialising of objects in Xamarin.iOS (Monotouch) using protobuf-net other than this method:

http://www.frictionpointstudios.com/blog/2011/3/31/using-protobuf-net-serialization-in-unity-iphone.html

Reading around some people claim they have managed it (without giving evidence), but my understanding is that [iOS  JIT==NO] so does not quite make sense.

If the only possible solution is to fully AOT all relevant classes what might a suitable pre/post-build event command line be to perform this AOT for any relevant assemblies automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've heard a good number of people have success via that route, but I too can't give documented evidence.

That method is a bit out of date - I've simplified a few steps; there is a standalone pre-compile tool that should work:

- create a project/assembly for the DTOs that you want to serialize that references the **appropriate version** of protobuf-net; presumably CoreOnly/ios, ideally with that dll set to copy into the output directory (it just makes life easier)
- run

  ```
  precompile "SomePath/YourDto.dll" -t:MySerializer -o:MySerializer.dll
  ```

  (maybe with a `mono` before that to get mono to host the exe)

  this should resolve the framework and compile a `MySerializer.dll` that you can reference, which involves zero JIT (`MySerializer.dll` will reference your dto dll and the version of protobuf-net that your dto dll referenced)
- now reference your dto dll, the serializer dll, and the protobuf-net dll, and it should all work just by using `new MySerializer().Serialize(...)`
- when you compile your solution, the projects should all AOT nicely

I'll be happy to offer guidance, but currently I am mac-less, so I can't check right now. If you get any problems let me know. If it can't resolve the framework, you can add `-f:{path to the framework assemblies}` to give it a clue.

Comment: Heya marc, thanks for the answer. Are you aware of a solution that does not require this precomiple step?

Comment: @MarcF to be optimal, I would recommend it. I gather you've had some joy with the Silverlight build - that might work, but won't be as fast (which won't matter if the data is small), but might hit some edge cases. I'll be interested to hear how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

I got protobuf-net 2 working on Xamarin-iOS by using the netstandard1.0 dll. You can get this dll by extracting the nuget package. No changes were needed.