# Protobuf-net on UWP/.NET Native and iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, protobuf-net, .net-native

I have a Xamarin.Forms App based on .NET Standard 1.4 that uses protobuf-net to store objects in the database that will be sent to a WCF service at a later time.

On Android and UWP "managed" everything works fine but - after searching through repositories, articles and blogposts that can no longer be accessed, and also after trying to get the precompilation tool to work, but failing at that - I have one simple (probably not) question: How do I get protobuf-net to work in "restricted" environments like UWP/.NET Native and iOS/Xamarin?

Comment: I've managed to do this once for Xamarin\IOS app (not Forms, but shouldn't matter). Was not easy and I used precompilation tool indeed. Unfortunately I don't have access to this codebase right now, just so that you know it's possible.

Comment: I know that it must be possible, but I can't figure out how :(

Comment: Same here, I did use protobuf-net on iOS, but neither did set it up for the project, nor have access to the code anymore. Did you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970850/2249175)?

Comment: Yes, but my problem is, that I can't get the project for the precompile tool to compile. Also any links to his blog are dead.

Comment: @EaranMaleasi blog links should work fine - any specific things that are 404?

Comment: @MarcGravell Firefox and Chorme (on different machines) are telling me, that the connection was closed while loading the website. Chrome specifically says `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`. All Plugins (Like Adblock, Noscript, etc.) are off.

Comment: @EaranMaleasi great: what url are you using?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm using `https://blog.marcgravell.com` but I just tested it with chorme on my mobile phone which works just fine. I then used an hotspot to connect a machine through my phone to the internet, and it did load aswell. Seems to be an internal issue.

Comment: @EaranMaleasi yeah, I'm seeing traffic to that, so if there's a problem: it isn't *everywhere*

Comment: @EaranMaleasi what about going for google implementation of protocol buffers in c#?

Answer (score 18):

Right now I don't have a great solution for this scenario. I know some people have made it work, but I'm not expert enough in UWP / Native / iOS to give you reliable "here's the path to success" instructions.

UWP / .NET Native and iOS share (as you know) a common issue: lack of full runtime emit. I understand *why this is*. It is just: tricky.

Historically, protobuf-net has tried to solve this problem via a build tool that repeated the existing IL-emit usually done at runtime - as a build-time tool. This was ugly and nasty, but it *worked*. Kind of. To hack around some platform restrictions, protobuf-net used some of the IKVM tooling to help with this, but as the .NET framework scene has continued to expand this is basically not viable. Plus: the IKVM tool is now abandoned and won't be being maintained.

*In parallel with this*, there is increasing impetus to investigate some newer concepts:

- full `async`/`await` for asynchronous IO sources: note that this is *extremely* unfriendly to IL emit, but is almost embarrassingly easy to implement in C#
- "pipelines" / "channels" / "streams 2" - whatever it is being called this week; but: the new allocation-free IO concept that is being used in Kestrel (I helped kick this ball around a little bit when it was in the early stages, so I'm familiar with what needs doing) - note that this *also* ties into `async`/`await`
- and of course: how all of the above relates to pre-generation

Right now, I'm very much of the opinion that the best route forward is for the pre-gen scenario to switch to emitting C# via build-time tooling. I have repeatedly petitioned MS for improved automated C# emit based on Roslyn, but so far: no joy (vexingly: the asp.net stuff even had a fully working proof-of-concept, but it is shelved). So *right now* I'm thinking: we need to assume that isn't going to happen, and basically write it independently. This isn't *necessarily* as complex as it sounds (and: codegen of various forms is very familiar to me). The advantage of C# emit here is that I don't need to fight the intricacies of every framework - I just need to make it compile (well, and run, obviously).

So: what's holding me back? In theory: nothing. I just need to get this stuff written and deployed. In reality: life, time, etc. I am guilty of prioritising things that *impact me daily*, and the reality is that I'm not really a daily user of those platforms, which means I'm not feeling the pain that you're feeling. But: I hear you loud and clear, and I am trying to ramp up the v3 work that should address these points. I genuinely want to *have* a good story for those things - and my aim is that by moving to a C#-emit model (for pre-gen, at least): it *helps me*. And if it *helps me* I know it won't be the forgotten toy in the attic / basement that I *know is there* but which it is hard to find the motivation to go to the trouble of finding.

Comment: So, for short, you are telling me either to get `precompile` working, or wait until you've finished v3 of Protobuf-net?

Comment: @EaranMaleasi I don't know; but *my educated guess* is that the work for me to revisit precompile in the context of each of those frameworks is comparable or larger than the work for me to get a viable C# emit

Comment: So, do you have an ETA for this new version, which is supposed to work on all plattforms?

Comment: @EaranMaleasi no, I don't; that's where the "life, time, etc" comes in; ultimately my day job isn't to write libraries, so this all comes out of my free time (unless it is something that I can very genuinely say "yup, this is hurting my employer and fixing this would help them" - which doesn't really apply to UWP / iOS / etc). I don't think there's a vast amount of work involved, but: the time of year means it is quite busy with family things etc. So, no: I don't have an ETA *that I would commit to*

Comment: Okay. I have a deadline right ahead,so I'll be switching to like json or something temporarily. But I'll be watching protobuf-net closely and switch as soon as possible. Have a nice time with your family :D